# Calabi-Yau structures on dg-categories

Tags: homological-algebra, mirror-symmetry, calabi-yau, string-theory, dg-categories

A (smooth) dg algebra is called (left) Calabi-Yau if (see for example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.09099.pdf))
$$ A^! = A[-n]$$
Here we use the inverse dualizing complex $A^!=\mathbf{R}\operatorname{Hom}_{(A^e)^{op}}(A,A^e)$. In topological string theory (e.g. in the context of matrix factorizations, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.4713.pdf) or [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.5847.pdf)), it is interesting to regard $A$ as a dg-category and form a sort of Yondeda-embedding $\hat{A} := \operatorname{Int}(A-{\operatorname{Mod}})$ defined in [Toen](http://www.mi-ras.ru/%7Eakuznet/dgcat/Toen%20Lectures%20on%20DG-categories.pdf) of it, the full subcategory of fibrant-cofibrant objects in the category of $A$-dg-modules.
9
My questions are the following:

- Is the dg-category $\hat{A}$ (where the dg-structure is inherited from $A-{\operatorname{Mod}}$ automatically a Calabi-Yau $A_\infty$-category when regarded as an $A_\infty$-category? So, are both of these definitions of Calabi-Yau compatible? Due to the work of [Costello](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412149.pdf), that would be required for the above construction to actually define a TCFT, and it is often stated it actually does - however I have never actually seen a discussion of this subtle point.
- If this is not always the case, is the homotopy category of $\hat{A}$ at least a Calabi-Yau category?